# Accessing site's root from themes folder

Tags: php, directory, constants

Having some troubles with a PHP script I am trying to build.

I need to access the a file which is located in the root folder of my Wordpress install:

**wordpress-root/live-config.php**

Problem is, my script file is located inside the theme's root folder, and I'm trying to access the root folder when defining a constant.

My script file is located in: **root-directory/wp-content/themes/theme-root/**

If I use `require ABSPATH . 'live-config.php';` it's no good because it looks in the directory where your current file is (ie. **theme-root** directory instead of my **wordpress-root**).

I just want to know what the best way would be to grab the root folder of my Wordpress install when defining a constant which is in the theme directory?

In my script, I'm currently trying:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/**
* Define type of server
*
* Depending on the type other stuff can be configured
* Note: Define them all, don't skip one if other is already defined
*/

define( 'WP_DEV_SERVER', file_exists( ABSPATH . 'dev-config.php' ) );

/**
* Load DB credentials
*/

if ( WP_DEV_SERVER )
    require ABSPATH . 'dev-config.php';
else
    require ABSPATH . 'live-config.php';
```

But obviously defining ABSPATH in my **theme-root** does not actually point to the **wordpress-root** directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're talking about a site specific `wp-config.php` file that resides in your themes folder.

At the point where you're loading the `wp-config.php` file, WP isn't fully loaded, so you ain't got any constants or filesystem API or other basic API functions available.

Here's how I approach this:

### Structure

```
# Dir structure
~/ROOT
├── config
├── wp-content
│   ├── themes
│   └── plugins
│   └── mu-plugins
```

Inside the `config` folder, I got *all* config files that are site specific. To identify them easily, they're named after the domains they're used on.

### The `wp-config.php`

```
# Config file suffix
! empty( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ) AND $suffix = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
! isset( $suffix ) AND ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) AND $suffix = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

# CONFIG FILE PATH: Sub of root ~/config
$config_path = dirname( __FILE__ ).DS.'config';

// inside wp-config.php
# LOAD CONFIG FILE
// local
if ( file_exists( "{$config_path}/_local.php" ) )  
{
    require( "{$config_path}/_local.php" );
}
// Stage
elseif ( file_exists( "{$config_path}/{$suffix}-stage.php" ) ) 
{
    require( "{$config_path}/{$suffix}-stage.php" );
}
// Production
elseif ( file_exists( "{$config_path}/{$suffix}.php" ) ) 
{
    require( "{$config_path}/{$suffix}.php" );
}
unset( $suffix, $config_path );
```

### Explanation and drawbacks

`DS` is just a short constant made to wrap `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. As I use it in lots of places and like to hold my lines short, I set it.

So the `$suffix` is what I retrieve from the `SERVER_NAME` or the `HTTP_HOST`. The point is that you can't be sure which one is set. Therefore I'm testing both.

The `$config_path` simply is the path of the current file + a folder named `config` on level below it.

The files themselves are named `example.com.php`. So I can find them easily by just identifying the domain and I'm done. This helps keeping things clean.

The first check that I do is for a `_local.php` file which holds my local configuration. I skip that step by deleting those lines for files I use on servers. It's just there to let my local setup run.

The second check is for the `stage` file. This will also get deleted on production sites.

I hope this helps other people avoiding things like [the setup shown here](https://gist.github.com/3998108).

Comment: Thanks for this kaiser, a very good insight. I will attempt to do something similar for my setup. Certainly solves my issue even though I have to change a few things around.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at this answer over at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356526/1077363 - it looks similar to the method I used once before but don't have that code to hand right now.

The theory behind it is that you are usually only 2 or 3 directories below the root directory, so checking for the existence of `wp-config.php` (which is most of the time stored int he root dir) using `file_exists()` will tell you if you've found the right directory. To get up directories use `dirname()` (if you nest them like in the other answer you will get there in fewer LOC).

Hope this helps, if you need more help I can dig out my old code later tonight.

Comment: Things like the one you showed [are already a meme on Twitter as you can see in this gist linked by pippin from pippinsplugins](https://gist.github.com/3998108).